# How to control route rendering in nuxtjs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, single-page-application, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

I read about [Goldpage](https://github.com/reframejs/goldpage),  this can control the route rendering

> **Render Control** - You can choose when and where your pages are rendered: one page can be rendered to both HTML and the DOM (classic SSR), another page can be rendered to HTML only (good old plain HTML like in the 90s!), and a third page can be rendered to the DOM only (classic SPA).

now, how can I do that in nuxtjs?

Comment: You can't. You have to choose between SPA or Universal (Server Rendered).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [NuxtJS](https://nuxtjs.org/guide#server-rendered-universal-ssr-) you are only able to chose one or the other (at the time of writing this). Their docs do mention [Vue SSR vs. Prerendering](https://ssr.vuejs.org/#ssr-vs-prerendering) which may help you, depending on your intended use case. It's not necessarily practical to mix between SSR & SPA; they are intended to solve different problems.

SSR is intended to improve Search Engine Optimization and page load speed, by rendering everything that the browser will need before it is sent to the client.

On the other hand, SPA's are rendered on the client-side and dynamically render content.

While I was looking for more information on this topic though, I discovered that there is a concept of [Isomorphic Applications](https://medium.com/capital-one-tech/why-everyone-is-talking-about-isomorphic-universal-javascript-and-why-it-matters-38c07c87905) which sounds like something that you are targeting here.